# Python Regex does't take all groups in a match

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex in python which returns all http[s] links with unsubscribe or opt out before the link.

```
(unsubscribe|opt out).*(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*))
```

My problem: if in a match there are 2 links, the regex will return the last one and not the first. For example

```
blablablablabla unsubscribe blablabla http://link1.com blablabla http://link2.com
```

Link 2 will be a group, not link 1

Does anyone know how to get link 1 as a group??

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/OKGjRi/1. Use a non-capturing group with `(?:unsubscribe|opt out)`

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure that you'll find a single RE to do this, but you could try two. First you match your string against:

```
(unsubscribe|opt out)(.*)
```

Then extract Group 2 from that match. And pump Group 2 through a second RE:

```
(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*))
```

which will return one match for each link. If I do this with your example I get:

```
Group 2 = blablablablabla unsubscribe blablabla http://link1.com blablabla http://link2.com
```

and then on the second test:

```
Match 1, Group 1 = http://link1.com
Match 2, Group 1 = http://link2.com
```

There is an awesome regex tester here:

https://regex101.com/

That I have bookmarked for testing such scenarios quickly.

Comment: @yivi your comment is a little misleading. Bernd says "i'm not sure" and then offers a solution that uses two. Your comment seems to intend that a single expression is possible, but comes off sounding like the entire solution (e.g. using two single expressions) is wrong (read: "doesn't work").

Comment: @yivi I clicked the link you provided but don't see a solution. I might ask kindly that if the comment provides one, it simply be posted as an answer in a way that anyone can see how to works. But as TylerH notes, I was only sharing how I'd approach it in a hurry ... noting that a one-liner may be possible too.